# CrystalReports paging issue

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have such issue with Crystal Report paging. When I load my report with multiple pages in it the paging behaves very strange. In report's toolbar it shows current page number and should show total page count (for instance, 1 / 6). But paging looks like this - 1 / 1 +.

The ReportSource property of a reportviewr is set in Page_Init.

Do you have any ideas..?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: CR at times do not show up the no of pages on ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

The Page Server is responsible for rendering RPTs into a format (EPF) suitable for the viewer control.  Its goal is to return the first page of the report as rapidly as possible.  Consequently, you may see different parts of the page render before others (textual elements before charts, for example).  The group tree, if the report contains one, is usually the last to render.

Moreover, you may notice that the page numbering is unusual.  This indicates that the Page Server has not finished rendering the entire RPT.  Once this has completed, the proper starting and ending page numbers should appear.

Read the section titled [Crystal Reports Page Server](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxi/en/en/BOE_SDK/boesdk_com_doc/doc/boesdk_com_doc/Architecture2.html).

Comment: thank you for your response. Do you know, is there any way to refresh the page numbers after RPT file is loaded?

Comment: I don't know.  You might investigate the Viewer SDK.